# Python imports are extremely slow

Tags: python, spyder

Python imports are extremely slow. Some examples include:

- pandas ~ 8s
- numpy ~ 4s
- ants ~ 40-120s (larger package named antspyx)

My collegues use the exact same hardware, but for them it runs much faster (factor 10). I believe the problem arose when upgrading to ubuntu 20.04. This upgrade caused some problems with the distutils associated with python3.6. In my quest to fix this problem, I might have messed something up. Maybe the problem extends beyond python as Spyder (an otherwise lightweight IDE) takes up to 5 minutes to start. Any help on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated. So far I have tried this:

- Updating ubuntu and python packages
- Rebooting ubuntu
- Running "top" to spot other processes that might steal cpu or memory resources
- Using tuna to analyze the import time of ants. The results revealed no single culprit to the long import time

Comment: Have you tried using a different Python version? It might take up more storage than desirable but you could try doing the same on Python 3.9?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I failed to mention that I have already tried with both python3.8 and python3.6 and there is minimal difference in import times. Does this possibly hint that the issue is not related to python at all?

Comment: Not entirely. If the packages are installed to `/usr/lib/python3/` then all Python 3 versions import the same library files; and if those library files are the problem (corrupt or just... broken) then switching versions won't really do much.

Did you try reinstalling the library files at all? This may require manual removal and might be a royal pain if the libraries are rather large.

Comment: I believe they are not installed in `/usr/lib/python3` but rather in `/usr/lib/python3.x` . The former folder contains only `dist-packages`. As far as I can test, installing a package in python3.6 does not make it available in python3.8. I have tried reinstalling ants using `--upgrade --force-reinstall`, but it did not have an effect.

Comment: That sub-folder is supposed to be there, so at least your packages are in the correct place! Not sure what else you can try, but it then seems Python may not be the problem. I'm not sure what could have broken your Python imports if I am honest, I have never heard of an issue like this. Apologies.

Comment: @MaybeLBDidIt Thank you for giving it a shot! I am quite baffled also.